# How can I see in Javascript if the element of an array is in an odd or in an even position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, numbers

For my program, I've to double the numbers of the array in an odd position and then, if that number is over 9, subtract 9 to it. If I had to do it with odd numbers I could easily do it with the following code(Numero is the name of the array):

```
for (var k = 0; k < Numero.length;k++) {
    if ( (Numero[k] % 2) != 0) {
        var doppioNumero = Numero[k] * 2;
        Numero[k] = doppioNumero;
        if ( Numero[k] > 9) { 
            var nuovoNum = Numero[k] - 9; 
            Numero[k] = nuovoNum;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do NOT have to do it on odd numbers, I've to do it on numbers in odd positions, like the first number, the third, the fifth, the seventh, the ninth and so on. How can I do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: `for (var i = 1; i < Numero.length; i += 2) {
  Numero[i] = (Numbero[i] * 2) % 9;
}`

Comment: just simply do it over **k** since it's the position and more precisely k+1

Comment: What do you mean by "odd positions"? What are the specific numeric indexes that should be set? By "first number" do you mean `0` or `1`? What is input array and expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `- 9` seems wrong if you are trying to get the last digit. For example 11 - 9 is 2. To get the last digit you can use `Numero[i] = Numbero[i] * 2 % 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to

```
for (var k = 0; k < Numero.length;k++) {
    if ( (k+1)&1) {
        var doppioNumero = Numero[k] * 2;
        Numero[k] = doppioNumero;
        if ( Numero[k] > 9) { 
            var nuovoNum = Numero[k] - 9; 
            Numero[k] = nuovoNum;
        }
    }
}
```

which would check at odd positions

Comment: i would say k+1

Comment: Could you please explain me what & exactly does and how you used it in your answer ? Documentation is not very helpful.

Comment: It checks if the 0'th bit is set or not, since odd number have it set and even don't

Comment: and using **&** is better than using the modulo division, it's faster.

Comment: there is nothing personnal but may i ask why you changed the accepted solution ? doing the iteration on the needed number isn't better than doing it on all the numbers + another treatement ? i have nothing against you @marvel308 :) just want to know why

Answer (score 0):

To check for odd positions, you simply have to check the value of k (modulo) 2:

```
for (var k = 0; k < Numero.length;k++) {
    if ( k % 2) != 0) {
        var doppioNumero = Numero[k] * 2;
        Numero[k] = doppioNumero;
        if ( Numero[k] > 9) { 
            var nuovoNum = Numero[k] - 9; 
            Numero[k] = nuovoNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < Numero.length; i += 2) {
  Numero[i] = (Numero[i] * 2) % 9;
}
```

Comment: we should start by 0 not 1 ... 0 is the first postion

Comment: it should start from 0 due to the fact that indices in JS starts from 0 not 1

Comment: he's talking about "odd position" so first postion is odd which is 0 --"I've to do it on numbers in odd positions, like the first number, the third, the fifth, the seventh"--

Answer (score 0):

You can use map instead of a for loop

```
Numero.forEach((v, k, arr)=>{
  if(k%2==1) arr[k]=arr[k]*2 % 9;
});
```

Comment: if the number in the please explain the logic behind arr[k]*2 % 9... say the number is 18 ... the answer should be 18-9 = 9... but the equation is giving out 0. the question say if the number is greater than 9, substract it by 9...